# excel formula non trivial nested OR

Tags: excel-formula

how to form an IF function for the following statement:

**IF (1 or 2 happens) then IF 1 happens A happens and IF 2 happens B happens?**

Comment: if what 1 or what 2? :)

Comment: Unfortunately, your explanation doesn't make sense... Can you give an example with intended outputs??

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about ***nested IF statement***

Stick numbers `1, 2, 3` in cells `A1, A2, A3`, then in Cell `B1` stick the below formula and drag it down

```
=IF(A1=1,"A happens",IF(A1=2,"B happens","Neither A or B"))
```

And your results

[image: nested if]

Comment: I did not asked clearly enough; I am trying to construct an IF formula looking something like IF(1 or 2, then if 1 then A, then if 2 then B)         it is hard for me to formulate the problem. please try to see the intention

Comment: in other words IF 1 or 2 happens in X1 then IF 1 happened A will be in X2, if 2 happened B will be in X2)

Comment: what is X1? what is X2? whats A? whats B?

Comment: @engineer, mehow's formula is doing that, just simplier. your first 1 or 2 check is unnecessary as it can be handled by the innermost else clause of the ifs.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old problem but it seems to be left dangling because the OP
did not express himself well.
My answers is for the people whose searches bring themselves here.

The originals posters has a common problem in asking a question about Excel because they don't understand a fundamental point about excel solutions.

A cell formula can **only** set the value of the cell **it is in** using information from elsewhere in the sheet.

There is no action at a distance.

The OP idea that something can "happen" is not excel thinking.
The "happening" event has to be laid out as a set of calculations that
 each produce a piece for the event.  Each piece would then be put in a separate cell controlled by the if statement condition.

For example if the event was "show a schedule for the Day".
The test could be is it a Weekday or a Weekend.
Part of the schedule could be Wake up time, Breakfast Food, Clothes to Wear.
The options for Weekday/Weekend could be for each question 6am/10AM, Cereal/Eggs, and Suit/Jeans respectively.

Each item would be in its own cell displaying its result, this will take up 3 separate cells that will all depend on the day which is stored in yet another cell.

Each of the 3 results cells would have a formula that looks like this (in English not Excel):
For Wake up time:
if(Date in question is a weekday, display in this cell "6AM", otherwise display "10AM")

I do not intend to build an actual sheet out of this because my intent is to 
point out how to think in excel.

To summarize: to show a complex conditional result in excel you must show each of it parts in a different cells that all depend on one common cell.